# Tengo un problema con mi api de google analytics un poco estraño

Tags: google-api

como comentaba en el titulo estoy teniendo un problema con la api de google analytics ya que tengo instalado un plugin de wordpress de analytics y me tira error 404 con la api y cuando entro directamente en google analytics la información que me muestra solo es de un mes para hoy. El caso es que tenia mucha información de como 4 años atrás y no aparece nada de nada por ningún lado. Como se puede solucionar.

Comment: Hola. ¿Ese plugin está actualizado? ¿Migraste a GA 4? No sé si sabes que están cerrando la versión antigua de Google Analytics y cambiaron también a una nueva API. Verifica que el plugin está actualizado en ese sentido.

Comment: Lo primero darte las gracias y voy a revisar yo creo que si lo actualice pero tendré que chequear